# PostGIS adding point to an existing multipoint

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I use PostGIS and I would like to add a new point to an existing MultiPoint using ST_Collect.
The problem is that I got this error message:

> ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type
>   (MultiPoint) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at
>   assignment SQL state: 22023

What do you think? What is wrong in my code? The first ST_Collect runs successfully, but the second one is not.

My code:

```
DO $$ 
<<first_block>>
DECLARE
  geom Geometry (MultiPoint,0);
  astext varchar;
BEGIN 
geom=ST_Collect(geom,ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 4)'))); 
geom=ST_Collect(geom,ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 10)')));
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) INTO astext;
RAISE NOTICE '%',astext;
END first_block $$;
```

I tried with GeometryCollection instead of MultiPoint:

```
DO $$ 
<<first_block>>
DECLARE
  geom Geometry (GeometryCollection,0);
  astext varchar;
BEGIN 
geom=ST_Collect(geom,ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 4)')));
geom=ST_Collect(geom,ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 10)')));
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) INTO astext;
RAISE NOTICE '%',astext;
END first_block $$;
```

And I've got this error:

> ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPoint) does not match column type
>   (GeometryCollection) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block
>   line 9 at assignment SQL state: 22023

I tried with Multipoints too:

```
DO $$ 
<<first_block>>
DECLARE
  geom Geometry (MultiPoint,0);
  astext varchar;
BEGIN 
geom=ST_Collect(geom,(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 4)')));
geom=ST_Collect(geom,(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 10)')));
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) INTO astext;
RAISE NOTICE '%',astext;
END first_block $$;
```

Error message:

> ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type
>   (MultiPoint) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at
>   assignment SQL state: 22023

Comment: When you promise to PostGIS that you'll only assign MultiPoint values to a column, it keeps you to that promise. Note that, while legal, assigning a SRID of zero is very much not best practice. Instead use the correct SRID for the coordinate values.

Comment: I tried with MultiPoint everywhere, but the problem is the same. I added this code to my question. I agree with you regarding the SRID, but now it is irrelevant, I wanted to ask a simple question, so I simplified my code.

Comment: ST_Collect generates a collection, which is invalid for a MultiPoint column.

Comment: ...but `ST_Union` will help you keep your promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc on [`st_collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) describes this situation:

> If any of the input geometries are collections (Multi* or
>   GeometryCollection) ST_Collect returns a GeometryCollection (since
>   that is the only type which can contain nested collections). To
>   prevent this, use ST_Dump in a subquery to expand the input
>   collections to their atomic elements

So to use `st_collect` you would `dump` the existing multipoints to points, include the new point and finally re-collect them all

```
select ST_AsText(ST_collect(dump_geom))
FROM (
    select(st_dump('MULTIPOINT(-2 3,1 2)' :: geometry)).geom as dump_geom 
    UNION
    select 'POINT(10 10)' :: geometry
    ) sub;

----------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(-2 3,10 10,1 2)
```

Or, as suggested by @geozelot, you can rely on [`st_union`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) which will merge the points for you

```
 select ST_AsText(ST_Union('MULTIPOINT(-2 3,1 2)' :: geometry, 'POINT(10 10)' :: geometry));

----------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(-2 3,1 2,10 10)
```